# "This method only supports T = double" when creating LQR for MultibodyPlant<double>

Tags: drake

I am creating an LQR controller with the code below:

```
systems::controllers::LinearQuadraticRegulator(
            plant, context, Q, R,
            Eigen::Matrix<double, 0, 0>::Zero() /* No cross state/control costs */,
            actuation_port_index);
```

- `plant` is a reference of type `MultibodyPlant<double>`
- `context` is a reference of type `Context<double>`
- `Q` is of type `Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6>`
- `R` is of type `Vector1d`

Debugging with gdb shows that the error comes from `multibody_plant.cc`

```
MultibodyPlant<T>::CalcPointPairPenetrations
```

I'm not sure why it's not using `MultibodyPlant<double>::CalcPointPairPenetrations`

In case it matters, my `plant` object was loaded from an `sdf` file with the following lines

```
    auto pair = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(&builder, std::make_unique<MultibodyPlant<double>>(FLAGS_time_step));

    MultibodyPlant<double>& plant = pair.plant;

    const std::string model_filename = getSrcDir() + "/../res/plant.sdf";
    Parser(&plant, &scene_graph).AddModelFromFile(model_filename);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree that the error message is a bit obtuse, I suspect that the problem is real...  I'll bet you are modeling a system that has contact dynamics (perhaps by accident) and LQR doesn't know how to deal with the non-smooth mechanics.

When you pass in a `System<double>` to the LQR method, it converts it with `ToAutoDiffXd()`, then evaluates the dynamics (to get the linearization).  That's why the error is about `MultibodyPlant<AutoDiffXd>` (not `double`).  For your system, the dynamics require calling the collision engine, which is not fully differentiable (yet), so that error message is thrown.

Setting the `time_step=0` changes from a time-stepping model to a continuous time model and does change the interaction with the collision engine.  So it is possible that can help in some cases.

But the solution, I think, is to decide if you are including the collision elements only accidentally (via your SDF) -- e.g. you're not actually trying to implement physics.  If yes, try commenting them out in your SDF to get around this.  Perhaps we could/should offer some options that make it easier to have LQR ignore these.

UPDATE: I've opened https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/11120 to make this slightly better.

Comment: This might be worth a whole new question, but I'm actually trying to use LQR to control a no-slip wheel rolling on a ground, hence contact dynamics (between the wheel and the ground) does exist in my system.  In this case, how should I tweak the model to make LQR applicable?

Comment: I assume some of the things I can do is setting a huge static friction and ensuring the wheels and ground are in contact from the beginning (not sure about this point)

Comment: I don't think LQR is a good match for this system as you've described it?  You effectively have an over-parameterized system (if the wheel is described with a floating base) living on a constraint manifold.  In the full coordinates, the system would appear uncontrollable.  You would need something like http://groups.csail.mit.edu/robotics-center/public_papers/Posa15.pdf to treat that contact constraint properly.

Comment: N.B. the standard way to do control (e.g. balancing for a segway) would be to write your dynamics out in the minimal coordinates, then do LQR.

Comment: Thx!  I'll look into that direction!  (and yes, I do intend to make a balance segway)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behavior when `FLAGS_time_step` is greater than zero.

Setting `FLAGS_time_step` to `0.0` resolves the issue for me.

Thought, it looks like a bug.